# Query builder object doesn't see aliases in previously built object (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-builder

Here's my first query:

```
$base=\DB::table('user')->select('firstname as name');
```

and then I want to access aliased column in second query:

```
$base->select('name');
```

but I see error. I can access all columns from table user though. Is there a way to change it so I can use aliased name in the second query?

whole code here:

```
$base=\DB::table('user')->select('firstname as name');
var_dump($base->get());//Everything is ok, I see the aliases 
var_dump($base->select('name')->get);//I see nothing, there's no column 'name'
```

more code here:

```
function getPerson(){
    return \DB::table('user')->select('firstname as name', 'age');
}

function getPet(){
    return \DB::table('pet')->select('petname as name', 'age');
}

function getNames($var){
    return $var->select('name')->where('age', 10)->get();
}

$base = getNames(getPerson());//empty here
$base = getNames(getPet());//empty here
```

The main problem is I got a lot of different queries and I want to put aliases on them and then prepare data for diagram with another query

Comment: What do you mean in a second query? Please post the entire code so we can see the relation, because it sounds like you might be misunderstanding something here.

Comment: can u plz post result of var_dump($base->get()); ?

Comment: Please post full code how do you want to use the second query. Because `$base` already contain `name` as you want, I don't see the reason why do you want to do `$base->select('name')` again.

Comment: Please post full code. You should use `->get` as `->get()` and `->where('age', 10)` as `->where('age', '=',  10)` . Also you are selecting `name` 2 times. don`t see the reason why. How did you test if its empty? Do you see errors in your log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create permanent column aliases. But, you can create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html), which will contain fields named as you wish. And then point your model to this view as a regular table via [`$table`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) property of the model.